# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "más te vale"?

Tags: locuciones

La expresión "más te vale" la entiendo como un consejo o incluso una amenaza. Encontré algunos ejemplos relativamente antiguos:

> Fatiga alguna vez el amor, mas nunca mata. Y si él muere, más te vale que muera él que tú, o él sólo, que los dos juntos.
>
> <sub>Juan Justiniano, Instrucción de la mujer cristiana, 1528</sub>

---

> "amigo, non te confiessas a mí, ante te confiesas a Dios e si non te descubres Dios te descobrirá en el día del juyzio do será llegado todo el mundo e aquí non estamos sinon Dios e tú e se lo confiessas avrás absoluçión; otramente serás condenado, e amigo, más te vale que pierdas la vergüença ante mí que non seas porfaçado ante toda la corte çelestial e ante todo el mundo".
>
> <sub>Pedro de Cuéllar, Catecismo, 1325</sub>

¿Hay alguna explicación del origen de esta expresión y el sentido que se le da?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ha dicho @walen en su comentario, la expresión es literal. Entre los muchos significados de *valer*, vemos el siguiente:

> **[valer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bIEq7WY)**
>
> Del lat. *valēre* 'ser fuerte', 'estar sano', 'tener tal o cual valor'.
>
> 2. tr. Producir, dar ganancias o interés. U. t. en sent. fig. *La tardanza me valió un gran disgusto.*

Yo en el ejemplo que pone habría usado el verbo *[costar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B6gxicW)* u otros, pero como ves, se usa también *valer*. Así pues, la expresión *más te vale* significaría, según esta acepción, *te interesa más*.

Me han resultado llamativos tus ejemplos, dado que se ve cómo una expresión se ha mantenido inmutable con el paso de los años. Veamos el significado del verbo *valer* en diccionarios anteriores:

> *Significa assimismo ser una cosa de importancia, ù utilidad para la consecucion, ò el logro de otra.* (Diccionario de Autoridades, 1739)

Estoy intentando buscar la definición en el diccionario de Covarrubias, pero curiosamente no aparece. Buscando más atrás podemos ver cómo se traducía vale a otros idiomas en el siglo XVI:

- Como *importar*, en 1570.
- Como *valer un precio* o como *equivaler*, en 1516 y en 1495.

En todo caso, estos diccionarios no era muy exhaustivos y solo daban traducción a las acepciones principales de cada palabra. Por tus ejemplos se ve que la acepción de *valer* como *interesar* o *importar* ya existía en el siglo XIV.

Date cuenta además de que la expresión *más te vale* es personal dado que supone que estás hablando con alguien. Pero la forma impersonal también se ha usado mucho:

> *Más vale páxaro en la mano que buytre bolando.* (c 1507)
>   *¡Más vale grano de pimienta que libra de arroz!* (1438)
>   *Más vale seso que ventura, que riqueza, nin linage.* (c 1330)
>   *Más vale que enfermo a paraíso vayas que sano e valient en el infierno cayas.* (c 1236)
>   *¡Más vale que nós los vezcamos que ellos cojan el pan!* (c 1140)

Igual que antes, la expresión *más vale* significaría *interesa más* o *importa más*.